# How do I pass object from one ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a RootViewController that calls an AddQuoteViewController and there is a variable "subject_id" that I set in the RootViewController that does not show up in AddQuoteViewController and I need help understanding why and how to fix it.

```
    Subject *sub = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.subject_id = sub.subject_id;

    [self addQuote_Clicked: sub];
```

...

```
- (void) addQuote_Clicked:(id)sender {

    if(aqvController == nil)
        aqvController = [[AddQuoteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddQuoteView" bundle:nil];

    if(addNavigationController == nil)
        addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aqvController];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Then in my AddQuoteViewController I try to access this variable like this:

```
RootViewController *rv = [RootViewController alloc] ;

NSLog(@"rv.Subject_id = %d", rv.subject_id);
```

But get nothing.  There must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Access Objects from one ViewController to another ViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704524/how-to-access-objects-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller). This is a *very* frequently asked question, so if the one linked here isn't exactly what you're looking for, keep looking -- there are many variations on this theme available.

Comment: Thanks Caleb but I did spend a bit of time looking and didn't find the clear direction I got in the other posts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this, but a short answer - You can set a reference to the RootViewController as a property on your AddQuoteViewController

i.e.

in AddQuoteViewController.h

```
RootViewController *rvc
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) RootViewController *rvc;
```

and corresponding synthesize and release in your implementation class. (AddQuoteViewController.m)

Then when you create your AddQuoteViewController inside your RootViewController, also set this property:

```
- (void) addQuote_Clicked:(id)sender {

    if(aqvController == nil)
        aqvController = [[AddQuoteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddQuoteView" bundle:nil];
    aqvController.rvc = self;
... etc.
```

Then you can access any property of the root view controller inside your AddQuoteViewController via this property:

```
NSLog(@"rv.Subject_id = %d", self.rv.subject_id);
```

As a side note there are a few things you are doing in your question that are a bit unusual, like trying to get a reference to an object by allocating a new one, and also creating a new navigation controller and presenting it as a modal view controller typically you would do one or the other (and wouldn't need to create a new navigation controller).  i.e. you would either create a view controller and present it modally, or you would create a view controller and push it onto your current navigation controller stack.

Comment: Wouldn't this become a circular reference?  That might add some complexity to memory management, though I'm not yet very familiar with ARC if that's what's being used here.

Comment: Thanks for this direction.  I understand my code is a bit wildcat - thats because I am literally finding my feet and fumbling around in the process.

Comment: Mr Jefferson - good point - because the aqvc is a member of rootvc, when it releases it will still be retained by aqvc. So to avoid this problem its probably better to make the property in aqvc an assign property rather than retain in this case. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's an error in your third block of code.  This:

```
RootViewController *rv = [RootViewController alloc] ;
```

Should be this:

```
RootViewController *rv = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
```

But strictly speaking that's not why you aren't seeing your instance variable.

If I understand correctly, the first two blocks of code are in `RootViewController`, and they instantiate an `AddQuoteViewController` and present it.  Then, from your third block of code, which is in `AddQuoteViewController`, you want to access a member variable (`subject_id`) of the `RootViewController` that brought it up.

The approach of instantiating a `RootViewController` from within the `AddQuoteViewController` wouldn't work, because you're creating a *different instance* of `RootViewController`.  What you're after is the value in the instance you just came from.

Perhaps the easiest way to do it is to create a corresponding property on `AddQuoteViewController` and set it when it's created:

```
- (void) addQuote_Clicked:(id)sender {

if(aqvController == nil)
    aqvController = [[AddQuoteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddQuoteView" bundle:nil];

if(addNavigationController == nil)
    addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aqvController];

aqvController.subject_id = self.subject_id;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

You'll need to create the `subject_id` property on `AddQuoteViewController` the same way you did on `RootViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  I take it that my AddQuoteViewController would have to have the subject_id variable already set up for the above to work right?

Comment: Yes.  You've already done it when you made it possible to say `self.subject_id` and `sub.subject_id` in your first block of code.  `subject_id` will have been declared with a `@property` declaration like gamozzii's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables across view controllers like that.
Have a look at creating a singleton class which will be globally accessible.
One exception I think is you can access them in the AppDelegate, but it's not advisable to have global vars.

Comment: Singletons would work, technically, but that's almost certainly a poor design choice for the OP's problem. Singletons may have their place, but they can quickly destroy your app's design if they're abused. I would call this situation an abuse :)